# Spring MVC - Request mapping, two urls with two different parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible in Spring to have one method with two different urls with different params for each method?

Below is pseudo code

```
@RequestMethod(URL1-param1, URL2-param2)
public void handleAction(@ModelAttribute("A") A a, ...) {
}
```

At the same time ULR1 is mapped in some other Controller as

```
@RequestMethod(URL1)
public void handleAction1(@ModelAttribute("A") A a, ...) {
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update: It appears your question is completely different.

No, you can't have the same url with different parameters in different controllers. And it doesn't make much sense - the url specifies a resource or action, and it cannot be named exactly the same way in two controllers (which denote different behaviours).

You have two options:

- use different URLs
- use one method in a misc controller that dispatches to the different controllers (which are injected) depending on the request param.

---

Original answer:

No. But you can have two methods that do the same thing:

```
@RequestMethod("/foo")
public void foo(@ModelAttribute("A") A a) {
    foobar(a, null);
}

@RequestMethod("/bar")
public void bar(@ModelAttribute("B") B b) {
    foobar(null, b);
}
```

If I haven't understood correctly, and you want the same ModelAttribute, then simply:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/foo", "/bar"})
```

And finally - if you need different request parameters, you can use `@RequestParam(required=false)` to list all possible params.

Comment: @svlada you avoid it by placing it in the `foobar` method. But do you need different model attributes, or you need just different urls?

Comment: I need different URLs with different parameters.

Comment: but different request parameters, or different model attributes?

Comment: Different parameters. But URL1 pattern must be present in two different controllers.

Comment: Then use `@RequestParam(required=false)`

Comment: Well in Spring it is not possible that SAME url is present in two Different controllers :)

Comment: @svlada - I understood that you need _different_ urls. If you need the same url, then have one controller with multiple @RequestParam(required=false)

Comment: Well that is problem. I cannot couple logic in one controller. Somehow i have to find way to map on url to two controllers, based on different parameters.

Comment: it is still unclear what you are trying to achieve. One or two urls? The question titles says "two urls"

Comment: Maybe my question is not formulated well. I have one url and two controllers. One url must be mapped in both controllers but with different parameters.

Answer (score 2):

you can supply multiple mappings for your handler like this

```
@RequestMapping(value={"", "/", "welcome"})
public void handleAction(@ModelAttribute("A") A a, ...) { }
```

But if you want to use different parameters for each mapping, then you have to extract your method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value={"URL1"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleSubmit(@ModelAttribute("A") A command, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    return helperSubmit();
}

@RequestMapping(value={"URL2"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleSubmit(@ModelAttribute("A") A command, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    return helperSubmit();
}

private helperSubmit() {
  return "redirect:" + someUrl;
}
```